# Trying to convert list or get rid of quotes around list numbers

Tags: python, random

This program is number guessing. It generates 4 numbers and allows the user to take guesses. After each guess it will display number of numbers correct and the place they are in. I get no syntax error from running it however even if all numbers are correct it says none are. I believe this is because the number variable has no quotations and the guess list does. Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
from random import randint

    number = [(randint(0,9)), (randint(0,9)), (randint(0,9)), (randint(0,9))]



    while True:
        guess_int = (int(input('Guess a 4 digit number: ')))
        guess_str = (str(guess_int))
        guess = (list(guess_str))

        numcorrect = 0

        if guess == number:
            print('Correct!')

        elif number[0] == guess[0]:
            numcorrect = numcorrect + 1
            print('You got the first number correct')
        elif number[1] == guess[1]:
            numcorrect = numcorrect + 1
            print('You got the second number correct')
        elif number[2] == guess[2]:
            numcorrect = numcorrect + 1
            print('You got the third number correct')
        elif number[3] == guess[3]:
            numcorrect = numcorrect + 1
            print('You got the forth number correct')

        if numcorrect != 0:
            print('You got', numcorrect, 'numbers correct')

        if numcorrect == 0:
            print('You got no numbers correct')
```

Comment: The "guess" list contains strings while "number" contains integers. These are never equal. You have to convert one of it into the other datatype to compare.

Answer (score 1):

Bug fixing your program with some more..

```
from random import randint

number = [(randint(0, 9)), (randint(0, 9)), (randint(0, 9)), (randint(0, 9))]

print(number)

while True:
    guess_list_str = list(input('Guess a 4 digit number: '))
    guess = [int(g) for g in guess_list_str] # This is how you get rid of the quotes

    numcorrect = 0

    if number[0] == guess[0]:
        numcorrect = numcorrect + 1
        print('You got the first number correct')
    if number[1] == guess[1]:
        numcorrect = numcorrect + 1
        print('You got the second number correct')
    if number[2] == guess[2]:
        numcorrect = numcorrect + 1
        print('You got the third number correct')
    if number[3] == guess[3]:
        numcorrect = numcorrect + 1
        print('You got the forth number correct')

    if numcorrect != 0:
        print('You got', numcorrect, 'numbers correct')

    if numcorrect == 0:
        print('You got no numbers correct')

    if guess == number:
        print('Correct!')
        break  # Added code
```

Answer (score 0):

your `number` variable is a list of integers while the `guess` is a list of strings, you have to convert one first, I suggest to do something like this:

```
guess_int = int(input('Guess a 4 digit number: '))
guess_str = str(guess_int)
guess = list(map(int,guess_str))
```

and another thing is, based on the logic behind this problem, you should reconsider using `elif`, because if the first condition is fired, the other ones will be neglected though they might to have a chance. so you should use `if` instead to be logically true.

3rd point is, this while should stop somehow, or at least after solving one problem, the number to be guess should be refreshed. try to end it if received right answer or renew the number.